# How can I switch between the title menu themes?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

When I first loaded Final Fantasy 15, the title menu contained a dark theme

[image]

When I finished the main story and went back into the title menu to either continue playing or start a new game plus, the title menu switch to a light theme

> [image]

I prefer the dark theme, but I wouldn't mind using the light theme either. How can I switch between them manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, you are not able to do this manually. As you've noticed, the title screen changes once you have beaten the game.

From [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5k7skw/title_screen_change_question_minor_spoilers/):

> Delete your save files, lol. :-) Hope this helps your problem! So far that is the only solution, I really hope they let us change it in the future.. Or cycle them randomly everytime you open the title screen.

And from, [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FinalFantasy/comments/5gf7fq/ffxv_title_screen_after_end/), the desire to change titles at will implies the lack of ability to do so:

> I personally wish you could choose the original title screen musice (love the Somnus theme more than the one we get after winning).

**However**, from the same thread, it looks like the **background** (but *not* the logo) changes on a day-night cycle:

> User 1: ...but can you change it back to the original title screen? I kinda liked it.
>
> User 2: i'm not really sure, maybe if you start a new game and then return to title it might switch back.
>
> User 3: nahhh im running a second playthrough since a couple of days, and it did not change back. i rly hope there is some way to do it, because i rly prefer the darker one.
>
> User 2: oh if you just meant the background and not the logo then it's a day night cycle that it rotates through.

Comment: Well that's unfortunate

Answer (score -1):

Create a backup copy of these files, just for sure:
..\Steam\steamapps\common\FINAL FANTASY XV\datas\sound\resources\20001music2\jp\bgm_title.win.mab

..\Steam\steamapps\common\FINAL FANTASY XV\datas\sound\resources\20001music2\jp\bgm_title_noct.win.mab

Then, delete "bgm_title_noct.win.mab".
Create another copy of "bgm_title.win.mab" and rename it "bgm_title_noct.win.mab".

This will change the music. I don't know how to change the image, sorry.

Tried it, it works.